# MVC ajax update partial result from inside

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view `Index` which has a partial view `GetAlertData` referenced inside:

Index.cshtml

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <td>Message</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
        @Html.Action("GetAlertData", new { selectedAlertType = Model.SelectedAlertType })
    </tbody>
</table>
```

GetAlertData.cshtml

```
foreach (var alert in Model.UserAlerts)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @alert.Date.ToString("d")
        </td>
        <td>
            @alert.Message
        </td>
        <td>
            @alert.AlertTypeName
        </td>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Dismiss", "Dismiss", new { userAlertID = alert.UserAlertID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller code

```
    public PartialViewResult GetAlertData(string selectedAlertType = "All")
    {
        //create viewModel
        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Dismiss(int userAlertID)
    {
        alertModel.DismissAlert(userAlertID);
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); //does nothing, because ajax (?)
    }
```

The problem is this: I want the "parent" view to refresh the data from the "GetAlertData" Html.Action after clicking Dismiss. How can I get the "parent" view to rerun the `GetAlertData` after an alert is Dismissed? Returning a `RedirectToAction` does nothing because it's an ajax call.

I know I could set up a javascript method in the parent view, and then call that in the OnSuccess in the Dismiss ajax call, but that seems kinda messy and I was wondering if there's anything in the MVC framework or helper methods that would help me do this.

Comment: Two additional people have answered your question. Could you please at least acknowledge them and provide feedback as to whether they answer your question or not. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSmith One of them was me. So I'm waiting until I can mark my own answer as the answer (tomorrow).

Comment: Okay, understand (I've had a lot of ignored answers recently - leads to paranoia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I changed the redirect action from "Index" to "GetAlertData", and set the `UpdateTargetId` option to the same as it is in the parent view. After clicking the dismiss button, it replaces the content of the partial view with the new result.

The only thing that is smelly to me about this answer is that I have to reference the id of an element in the parent view (`"tableBody"`). I tried to wrap the whole child view in a div and replace that, but that resulted in the duplication and poor formatting. That might be partially because `<table><div><tr>` isn't exactly valid HTML.

New Child view code:

```
@{
    var ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "tableBody",
        HttpMethod = "Post",
    };
    if (Model.UserAlerts != null)
    {
        foreach (var alert in Model.UserAlerts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @alert.Date.ToString("d")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @alert.Message
                </td>
                <td>
                    @alert.AlertTypeName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Dismiss", "Dismiss", new { userAlertID = alert.UserAlertID }, ajaxOpts)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only two ways to update page content with something from the server: 1) Reload the entire page or 2) AJAX.

If you want to just update a portion of your page without causing a reload, then you must use AJAX to request some action that will return the information you desire and then JS to replace the portion of the page in the DOM. Since this is about essentially reloading a partial, you'll need an action that returns that partial. Also, since you're already using a child action, the same action can be used for this as well. Just make sure to remove `[ChildActionOnly]`, if present, so the action is exposed to the routing framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the ActionLink to a jQuery/Javascript click event then you can call the Dismiss from there returning a success/error flag. If the Dismiss was successfull then call the GetAlertData method with another Ajax call and use the returned HTML to replace the table body. You may need to make some other changes.